# Are there any function in C# that returns p-value associated with a chi-square goodness of fit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net, chi-squared, p-value

i'm new here and my English isn't very good, so i'll try to explain as well as possible.
I'm doing a web application in `ASP.NET` and `C#` about steganalysis. 
I was looking for internet a function that calculates the observed significance level, or p-value in a chi-square test
for my algorithm and I found it in Java:

This is the result of mi search:

`chi[block]= chiSquareTest(expectedValues, pod);`

`chiSquareTest(double[] expected, long[] observed)`

- Returns the observed significance level, or p-value,
- associated with a Chi-square goodness of fit test comparing
- the observed frequency counts to those in the expected array.

My question is, Are there any equivalent function in `C#` that returns the same parameter?

Thank you in advance,

Ana.

Comment: It would be useful to see what the Java code does rather than only getting the function prototype.

Answer (score 5):

The MathNet NuGet package contains the ChiSquared distribution - you can get the cumulative or inverse cumulative.

```
ChiSquared c = new ChiSquared(degreesOfFreedom);
return c.CumulativeDistribution(testValue);
```

Links:

- [MathNet.Numerics NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/)
- [MathNet.Numerics GitHub Repository](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics)
- [ChiSquared class and CumulativeDistribution method](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/306fb068d73f3c3d0e90f6f644b55cddfdeb9a0c/src/Numerics/Distributions/ChiSquared.cs#L184C40-L184C40)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I figured I'd post anyway.

The [Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/R_Project_Accord_NET.htm) framework has a library and NuGet package [Accord.Statistics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord.Statistics/3.8.2-alpha) which has a `ChiSquareTest` [class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Testing_ChiSquareTest.htm#!) that can be used in a similar manor as mentioned in your question:

```
ChiSquareTest chiSquareTest = new ChiSquareTest(observedArray, expectedArray, DOF);
chiSquareTest.PValue; // gets p-value
chiSquareTest.Significant; // true if statistically significant
```

The only thing is that  you'll have to calculate your DOF - degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an inbuilt function.

You should try looking for a library that contains the function or implement it yourself. 
A quick search returned me this
http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/distributions/chisquare.php

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432194/How-to-Calculate-the-Chi-Squared-P-Value

Comment: First of all, sorry for the delay. 
Thank you very much for the information, Marcom. I will try to solve it with the information you provide me. Thanks for the help.